# Extracting subdomains and their respective Ip addresses from strings using regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string, ip-address

Using a recon tool, I make an output of a list of lists, most containing  a subdomain and it's respective host address. I am trying make a a cleaner list of lists, one that only contains the subdomain and the IP  without the background output. Below is an example of the raw output parsed into smaller lists and the method of trying to extract the subdomains and the IP addresses using regex. However, no matter what I try in terms of the regex format or the re. I usually get a 'TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object'

Desired Output for single list:

```
['SUBDOMAIN', 'IP ADDR']

subdomain_list = []

raw_output = [["b'"], [' Performing General Enumeration of Domain: buzzfeed.com\\n[-] All nameservers failed to answer the DNSSEC query for buzzfeed.com\\n'], [' \\t SOA ns-1367.awsdns-42.org 205.251.197.87\\n'], [' \\t NS ns-1015.awsdns-62.net 205.251.195.247\\n'], [' \\t NS ns-1015.awsdns-62.net 2600:9000:5303:f700::1\\n'], [' \\t NS ns-166.awsdns-20.com 205.251.192.166\\n'], [' \\t NS ns-166.awsdns-20.com 2600:9000:5300:a600::1\\n'], [' \\t NS ns-1554.awsdns-02.co.uk 205.251.198.18\\n'], [' \\t NS ns-1554.awsdns-02.co.uk 2600:9000:5306:1200::1\\n'], [' \\t NS ns-1367.awsdns-42.org 205.251.197.87\\n'], [' \\t NS ns-1367.awsdns-42.org 2600:9000:5305:5700::1\\n'], [' \\t MX aspmx2.googlemail.com 74.125.205.27\\n'], [' \\t MX alt2.aspmx.l.google.com 74.125.68.26\\n'], [' \\t MX aspmx5.googlemail.com 74.125.195.27\\n']] #etc....

    for l in raw_output:
        subdomain = re.findall('[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z]+(\/[a-zA-Z0-9#]+\/?)*$', raw_output)
        host = re.findall('[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', raw_output)
        if domain and  if host:
            subdomain_list.append([subdomain, host])

    print(subdomain_list)
```

Comment: `raw_output` is passed to `re.findall` - that is wrong, as it is a list of lists. `re.findall` accepts a string, not a list.

Comment: Check [this approach](https://ideone.com/TEF7sk).

Comment: So, it did not work out, did it?

Comment: In the generic case you can not extract the subdomain just with a regex. You need something like the public suffix list. There are already numerous question about that. Also still in generic case you should provide exactly the error message your code generate (the stacktrace provides line numbers, so that should help you pinpoint where the problem is), and if the ouput desired is different from the one you get, you should clearly give examples of input and output contents.

Comment: Generic recommendation: prefix all strings containing a regex with `r`, otherwise you will get at least a warning about a `\` not in front of a character that you can expect, and at worst not at all the behaviour you expect.

Comment: Thank you  Wiktor Stribiżew! The changes you provided worked!!